Langchain RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain throwing ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'context'}
I have a multimodel RAG system that generates answers using the texts parsed from hundreds of PDFs that are retrieved from my Redis vectorstore. And I have several chains (RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain) to find relevant contextual texts from vectorstore and append them in my chatbot llm calls. I'm having problems in correctly adding context to the system prompt. Below code throws ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'context'} :
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain
from langchain.prompts import (
    ChatPromptTemplate,
    HumanMessagePromptTemplate,
    PromptTemplate,
    SystemMessagePromptTemplate,
)
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Redis


from chatbot_api import config

_INDEX_NAME = "Postmarket"

rds = Redis.from_existing_index(
    embedding=config.OPEN_AI_EMBEDDINGS,
    index_name=_INDEX_NAME,
    schema=config.INDEX_SCHEMA,
    redis_url=config.REDIS_URL,
)


_template = """Your job is to use information on the documents
to answer questions about postmarket operations. Use the following
context to answer questions. Be as detailed as possible, but don't
make up any information that's not from the context. If you don't
know an answer, say you don't know. If you refer to a document, cite
your reference.
{context}
"""

system_prompt = SystemMessagePromptTemplate(
    prompt=PromptTemplate(input_variables=['context'], template=_template)
)

human_prompt = HumanMessagePromptTemplate(
    prompt=PromptTemplate(input_variables=['question'], template="{question}")
)
messages = [system_prompt, human_prompt]

postmarket_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate(input_variables=['context', 'question'], messages=messages)

postmarket_chain = RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain.from_chain_type(
    llm=ChatOpenAI(model=config.QA_MODEL, temperature=config.TEMPERATURE),
    chain_type="stuff",
    retriever=rds.as_retriever(search_type="similarity", search_kwargs={"k": 8}),
    return_source_documents=True,
    # chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": postmarket_prompt}, # this also doesn't work throwing ValueError -> document_variable_name summaries was not found in llm_chain input_variables: ['context', 'question']
    verbose=True,
)
postmarket_chain.combine_documents_chain.llm_chain.prompt = postmarket_prompt

# Invoke
postmarket_chain.invoke("what are the postmarket activities i should follow?")

The RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain is supposed to use the Redis retriever and append the extracted texts to the {context} I believe, but seems like it can't or there's something else i can't see.
It surprisinly works when I use double brackets around 'context' in the prompt -> {{context}}. However, when I examine the logs of the intermediate steps of langchain trying to use the agent's tools to generate an answer, my understanding is that the context is not even passed and the llm model just uses its own knowledge to give answers without using any contextual info that's supposed to be passed from vectorstore. Here are some logs below. Notice how some text data returned from vectorstore is included in summaries but then when StuffDocumentsChain passed that to llm:ChatOpenAI you see that it's not injected into the system prompt (scroll right to see), the context field still remains as {context} (it dropped the outer brackets)
[chain/start] [chain:RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain] Entering Chain run with input:
{
  "question": "what are the postmarket activities i should follow?"
}
[chain/start] [chain:RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain > chain:StuffDocumentsChain] Entering Chain run with input:
[inputs]
[chain/start] [chain:RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain > chain:StuffDocumentsChain > chain:LLMChain] Entering Chain run with input:
{
  "question": "what are the postmarket activities i should follow?",
  "summaries": "Content: Contains Nonbinding Recommendations  \n \n 17 D ... (i'm cutting the rest but this info comes from the text chunks in vectorstore)"
}
[llm/start] [chain:RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain > chain:StuffDocumentsChain > chain:LLMChain > llm:ChatOpenAI] Entering LLM run with input:
{
  "prompts": [
    "System: Your job is to use information on the documents\nto answer questions about postmarket operations. Use the following\ncontext to answer questions. Be as detailed as possible, but don't\nmake up any information that's not from the context. If you don't\nknow an answer, say you don't know. If you refer to a document, cite\nyour reference.\n{context}\n\nHuman: what are the postmarket activities i should follow?"
  ]
}
[llm/end] [chain:RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain > chain:StuffDocumentsChain > chain:LLMChain > llm:ChatOpenAI] [1.91s] Exiting LLM run with output:
{
  "generations": [
    [
      {
        "text": "I don't have specific details from the provided context about the postmarket activities you should follow. Generally, postmarket activities can include monitoring the safety and effectiveness of a product, reporting adverse events, ensuring compliance with regulatory requirements, conducting postmarket surveillance studies, and engaging in quality improvement initiatives. If you have specific guidelines or a context document, please provide that for more detailed information.",
        "generation_info": {
          "finish_reason": "stop",
...

Am I right in my assumption of the context is not being passed to the knowledge window correctly? How can I fix this? All the examples I see from other projects use one bracket around context when they include it in the system prompt. However I could only make the code work with double brackets and that seems like it's not injecting the context at all...
Can this be due to the index schema I used when creating the vectorstore? the schema for reference:
text:
- name: content
- name: source
numeric:
- name: start_index
- name: page
vector:
- name: content_vector
  algorithm: HNSW
  datatype: FLOAT32
  dims: 384
  distance_metric: COSINE

